# How to package a custom kernel for Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, packaging

I've build a custom linux kernel from the vanilla source tree using the deb-pkg target:

```
make deb-pkg
```

After that package has been built I've got several .deb files. However I'd like to upload those files to a private repository which is managed by reprepro. I need a .changes file for that. I could generated the changes file with

```
dpkg-genchanges
```

This in turn needs a .dsc file which I don't have.

How do I generated a .dsc (and .changes) file from a vanilla linux source tree from which I've build .deb packages using make deb-pkg?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `make deb-pkg` gives you a source package, only a binary package, so there isn't really a `.dsc` file to be had.

To generate a changes file that you can use to upload to reprepro, use the `changestool` program that comes with reprepro:

```
changestool --create-with-all-fields kernel.changes add <deb-file>
```

You may need to edit the resulting changes file to fill out a few more things, like the target distribution, before reprepro is happy, but it should get you most of the way there.